# Hide element if box checked php based on post type wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to hide the HTML element from the front end of the listing using the checkbox

The box I'm trying to hide is a post type called

```
if(is_singular('estate_agent')){
```

the code I'm using to hind element on the front page is

```
 <?php 
$agent_phone      =   intval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'disabled_phone', true) );
if($agent_phone == 0){

?>
<html></html>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is your `disabled_phone` contain?

Comment: <input type="checkbox"  id="disabled_phone" name="disabled_phone" value="1" 
                    <?php if ($hide_phone == 1) { 
                        print'checked="checked"'; 
                        } 
                    ?>

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: if you dump the value of $agent_phone using print_r, i.e. print_r( $agent_phone ) what is returned?

Comment: Sorry for late reply , print    1